# Second shmget always returns access denied

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to create two sets of shared memory segments. One to store integers and the other one to store strings.
I keep getting an error on the second `shmget` call when I am creating the shared memory segment for my integers.

```
 keyS=5678;
 keyI=6789;
   //create shared memory for titles and categories
  if(stringsID=shmget(keyS,sizeof(char*)*lineCounter*2,IPC_CREAT|0666)<0)
    {
      perror("shmget");
      fprintf(stderr, "Titles Cannot create shared memory  errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));

      exit(-1);
    }

  //attach to shared memory
  if ((titlesSH = (char**)shmat(stringsID, NULL, 0)) ==(char**) -1)
    {
      perror("shmat");
      exit(1);
    }

  //titles start at titlesSH[0] while categories start at titlesSH[lineCounter]
  categoriesSH=titlesSH+lineCounter;


  //create shared memory for stock and codes
  if(intsID=shmget(keyI,sizeof(int)*lineCounter*2,IPC_CREAT|0666)<0)
    {
      perror("shmget");
      fprintf(stderr, "Stock Cannot create shared memory  errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));

      exit(-1);
    }
  //attach to shared memory
  if((stockSH=(int*)shmat(intsID,NULL,0))==(int*)-1)
    {
      perror("shmat");
      exit(-1);
    }
```

When I run `ipcs` in terminal I see that there are no ipcs with the keys that I am specifying in my code but I tried different keys and the result is always the same. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried removing `0666` from privileges when I am calling `shmget` and it does stop (`shmget` does not return -1) and let's my copy contents in but when I try to get the contents from it I get a segmentation fault.

If I remove the extra shared memory segment and keep only one everything is working fine. I know there is a workaround to this (store everything as a string in a single larger memory segment) but I also want to know why this occurs

**EDIT the workaround I noted above is currently working
I am storing all my information in a single shared memory segment that stores strings and it's size is the sum of the two segments I was trying to create. So shared memory space is not an issue. `ipcs` only gives me 9 ipcs running so I suppose the limit of ipcs and the limit of space are not the issue in this case

Comment: What does the `errno` tell you?  How many shared memory segments is your system configured to support?  (It's unlikely to be just one, but maybe the others are already in use.)  Is the second key already in use by some other program? What does `ipcs` show you?  When run by `root`?  (I see you say that it doesn't show you anything and you've tried varying the keys with the same effect.)  Could it be failing because you're trying to create too _small_ a segment?  The is a `shmmin` kernel parameter, and maybe the integers set is too small?  I worry about the size of your string space.

Comment: Well the thing is I am creating String pointers in the kernel and not the actual strings. now for the maximum ipcs I do not think I am reaching the limit given that I happened to ran 5 different programs concurrently all creating the same sized as my code above shared memory and it works ok. Unless the issue is that one process cannot create two different shared memory segments. what I currently have and works is I combined the two segments into one with strings only and convert ints to strings before sending them in. So I suppose shared memory space is not an issue.

Comment: running ipcs returns a number of ipcs controlled by system apps and mine. Mine's total bytes with the old code was 32 (linecounter is 4, I am creating two pointers for each line so total 32) and with the new code is double that (since again I am only creating string pointers) But again total limit of space for ipcs is not an issue as I combined the two segments in one and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
if(stringsID=shmget(keyS,sizeof(char*)*lineCounter*2,IPC_CREAT|0666)<0)
/* and */
if(intsID=shmget(keyI,sizeof(int)*lineCounter*2,IPC_CREAT|0666)<0)
```

Should most probably be:

```
if( (stringsID=shmget(keyS,sizeof(char*)*lineCounter*2,IPC_CREAT|0666)) < 0)
/* and */
if( (intsID=shmget(keyI,sizeof(int)*lineCounter*2,IPC_CREAT|0666)) <0)
```

---

To demonstrate,

1. compile the following program (does your compiler issue any warnings? mine does!)
2. Run it
3. do `ls -ltr`
4. run it again
5. do `ls -ltr` again

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void) {

int fd;

if (fd=open("omgwtf", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WTF!\n" ); }

fprintf(stderr, "fd=%d\n", fd );

return 0;
}
```

Note: for extra fun, you could add `O_EXCL` to the flags.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just check your precedence chart. (this kind of error is mostly seen with `open()`, but it works of course with any function call)

Comment: Forget my last comment, i read them the other way around (that's why I said please describe as it's a bit not readable, but still my initial fault anw). Yes that was what was causing my error